# Finding $\int \cos{x} \cos{2x} \cos{3x} \;dx$

Tags: integration, trigonometry

> Find 
>   $$\int \cos{x} \cos{2x} \cos{3x}\;dx $$
>
> This question is from Basic Mathematics. Please explain how I can solve it according to class 11th student.

My work is below:
$
\implies
\displaystyle\int\cos{x} \cos{2x} \cos{3x}\, dx\\
\implies\displaystyle\int\cos{x}(2\cos^2x - 1)(4\cos^3x - 3\cos{x}) \, dx\\
\implies\displaystyle\int\cos{x}(8\cos^5x-6\cos^3x-4\cos^3x+3\cos{x}) \, dx\\
\implies\displaystyle\int(8\cos^6x-6\cos^4x-4\cos^4x+3\cos^2x) \, dx\\
\implies\displaystyle\int(8\cos^6x-10\cos^4x+3\cos^2x) \, dx\\
\implies8\displaystyle\int\cos^6x \, dx-10\int\cos^4x \, dx+3\int\cos^2x \, dx\\
$

Now I'm unable to figure out what should I do next. I mean I know that $\displaystyle\int\cos{x}\,dx = \sin{x} + C$ but because of exponents I'm stuck here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is much simpler to use the formula $\cos \, A \cos \, B =\frac {\cos (A+B) +\cos (A-B)} 2$.

You should get $\frac 1 4 (1+\cos (6x)+\cos (4x)+\cos(2x))$ which is easy to integrate.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html